Strapi 4.25.11 (node v20.12.2) - Upgrade to 5 issue
I'm trying to upgrade my Strapi app using npx @strapi/upgrade major, but I keep getting the error: 'Cannot find module esbuild'. I've tried installing esbuild both globally and locally, but the issue persists. I'm using Node.js v20.12.2. How can I resolve this?
